# Pattern not correct with regular expressions in c#

Tags: c#

i am doing a project , and i want to remove from a string http protocoll. In my excel sheet there are two types one is http://www.email@domain.com and the other is http://email@domain.com.I have tried so many combinations but i can't find the right one.
My code only works with the first type and not with the second one

```
var website_domain_in_excel = list_of_information_in_excel[2];  
string pattern = "(http://\\www.)";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(website_domain_in_excel, pattern, String.Empty));
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: you should escape the slashes like this: `\/\/` and since the dot is a character class you should escape that one too: `\.`

Comment: If you just need to remove `http://` then just replace that - don't specify `www`. You  don't even need regex, a simple string replace would work.

Comment: i want to remove http://, and http://www. , bcs i downt know wich one will be next in my loop

Comment: @DiegoDeVita when i type your slashes like that i get red in code, thank you

Comment: yes you can ignore my comment and follow the other.. I was thinking without considering escaping strategies of literals according to the language. And the slash in regex don't need escaping as I thought before. Backslashes do.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you want is this:

```
string pattern = @"http:\/\/(?:www\.)?"
```

This matches `http://` and then an optional non-capturing group matching `www.`.

You can see an explanation of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/IEfeTA/1) and [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sPCOjc) for a working demo in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string: "http?://?www.|http?://" which matches either "http://www." or "http://".

The code would look like this:

```
var website_domain_in_excel = list_of_information_in_excel[2];  
string pattern = @"http:\/\/www.|http:\/\/";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(website_domain_in_excel, pattern, String.Empty));
```

Comment: the only problem is with this \/, my editor marks it as red as says unrecognized build error,thank you

Comment: My bad, i forgot to put in the @ symbol in the beginning, the string would look like this: @"http?:\/\/?www.|http?:/\/"

Comment: What's the intention of 3 `?` here? This makes the `p` optional and, in the first case, the second `/` optional. So `htt:/www.email...` would match.

Comment: The 3 ```?```was a mistake when writing the pattern, i have removed them now, thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex solution:

```
var eml = "http://www.email@domain.com";
eml = eml.Replace("http://", "").Replace("www.", "");
// eml now is "email@domain.com"
```

You might want to test that that "www." only appears at the start. The (unusual) "email@www.domain.com" should remain intact.

---

But if you really want a regex:

```
eml = Regex.Replace(eml, "^https?://(www\\.)?", "");
```

- This also catches "https", because of the `?` after that "s"
- It will also find and replace an optional "www.", but only at the start